# orgmode read/source all options from a template file

Tags: org-mode

i was wondering if orgmode had a simple way to read/source all options from a template file. for example instead of adding all this to every presentation file i create:

```
 #+OPTIONS: reveal_center:t reveal_progress:t reveal_history:nil    reveal_control:t
 #+OPTIONS: reveal_center:t 
 #+OPTIONS: reveal_rolling_links:t reveal_keyboard:t reveal_overview:t num:nil
 #+OPTIONS: reveal_width:1200 reveal_height:800
  #+OPTIONS: toc:nil
  # #+REVEAL: split
  #+REVEAL_MARGIN: 0.1
  #+REVEAL_MIN_SCALE: 0.5
```

i would just source a file (txt or orgmode?) with all the pre definitions

any clue?

Comment: Please don't post duplicate here and Org list.

Answer (score 2):

Ok got it, you can "source" a template file by using the SETUPFILE option , ie;

```
#+SETUPFILE: /home/zeltak/org/files/Uni/Courses/templates/org.options.reveal.org
```